# Force user to migrate from iphone or ipad application to universal

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

We have separate application for iphone and ipad. Now customer expecting make a universal application. After universal application successful release how do we force the both user (iphone and ipad) to migrate universal application? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's little you can do to force them to move. Gentle pushing is your only real option.

You could issue an update with a suggestion that they switch. If you control the server-side (if there is one) you could start refusing to serve the non-universal app as long as you give a suitable error message.